# Hive :: Simple arithmetic calculation with decimal numbers returning NULL

Tags: sql, hive, amazon-emr

The below query reuturns null

```
hive> select  2.77047767262313*0.361901756864543*(91.57/380364.029999943);
OK
_c0
NULL
Time taken: 0.036 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

But the same query when the parenthesis is removed, it works

```
hive> select  2.77047767262313*0.361901756864543*91.57/380364.029999943;
OK
_c0
0.00024137879781663538674308
Time taken: 0.04 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Any particular reason for this behaviour?
Its run on EMR. Hive 2.3

Comment: http://phelpsmath.weebly.com/uploads/3/1/5/2/3152977/6th_sect_2-6.pdf

Comment: Somewhere among the way one of the operations doesn't fit into the resulting type.

Answer (score 0):

When you do not mention output data type, hive returns data in double format.

For first query, it may cross limit of double data type so its showing null. Btw, in my system first sql is returning data.
Second SQL may be returning something which is fitting in double data type.

Pls note, double(floating point) is a data type which store very close approximations of numeric values - which makes it flexible to store different decimal formats but data can be incorrect.

So, you can use something like below SQL to get consistent result and cast the result to decimal.

```
select  cast( 2.77047767262313*0.361901756864543*(91.57/380364.029999943) as decimal(38,30));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If that was the case, how does it work when the parenthesis is removed? I am trying to find the logical reasoning behind that. And the suggested casting returns null too  for me.

Comment: I am not exactly sure about why removing () is giving some result. Did you check if the result is correct? Like shawnt said, it has to do the default return data type. And return data type here is double which returns approximate value. Now, did you cast your second sql and try? I think that will return null too. Another thing you can try - cast to decimal (38,37) may be and see.